# Two Quantity Selectors in Woocommerce Add to Cart

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

I am trying to create a "Contact Lenses" Online store using WP and Woocommerce.As you know Woocomerce generate one default quantity display for each product as:

[image]

but in my case I need to have TWO Quantity Selectors for each product , one for Right Eye and second for Left eye as:

[image]

can you please help me to figure this out how to have two selectors and eventually add the sum of these two into the Cart or display both quantities in the Cart?
Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to sell lenses the right way? I am finding WooCommerce variations insufficient. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use the built in variation functionality? This way you can then have as many "quantity" fields as you like.

You could setup 2 variations of the product called Right OD and Left OS and have a drop down with the quantities.

This will be by far the best solution for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks danyo, Can you please let me know where I can find a tutorial or sample ding like this? I couldn't find any thing thing!

Comment: Thanks but to mu understanding do I have to do this process for every product? I mean I have 1500 products so I have to do this for each of them one by one!

Comment: WooCommerce has a function to allow you to add the same variations to all products.

Comment: Thanks there is still one issue here which I need to add the sum of the two variations in Quantity box, I am going to follow this in a new post by the way thanks for your hints

Comment: People generally buy both lenses (OS and OD) together. Two variations with a dropdown is never seen on any eCommerce store selling lenses.